# Accessing "What are you up to"-comments on foursquare

Tags: api, comments, foursquare, hashtag

I am working on a foursquare application where I am depending on user-generated data.

Say for instance that I want to categorize places with rare tap beers on the menu, then I would like users to write in their "What are you up to"-comment something like #RareBeer Pabst Blue Ribbon, and be able to catch that comment.

I understand that my OAuthed user has to befriend users to be able to see this, but how do I proceed from there?

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you to go about this would be to use the Real-Time APIs we detail here: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime.

Once you set up a Push API consumer, you will be able to get checkins from your OAuthed users sent directly to your server as they occur. Each push will include the shout, if there was one, allowing you to parse the comments your users are leaving as they come in. This is the method that apps like Hashtag Mom ( http://hashtagmom.com/ ) use to be able to gather and act upon user shouts ASAP.